# How to draw highest price of the previous month in the lower timeframes in Pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I want to draw the highest price of the previous month horizontally in the lower timeframes.
How to draw a line that starts from the first candle of the previous month in lower timeframes?

```
line.new(x1 = time[1] , y1 = a, x2 = time , y2 = a, xloc = xloc.bar_time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the high value of the previous month with the `request.security()` function.

Then use the built-in variable `time` and built-in function `timestamp()` to figure out first candle of the month.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

high_month = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", high[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

targetDate = time >= timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow), 1, 0, 0, 0)
beginMonth = not targetDate[1] and targetDate

var line l_high_month = na

if (beginMonth)
    l_high_month := line.new(bar_index, high_month, bar_index+1, high_month, extend=extend.right, color=color.green)
    line.delete(l_high_month[1])

plotshape(beginMonth, "T", shape.triangleup, location.belowbar, size=size.small)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. another question, how can I change the code to draw this line from its own candlestick (highest high in month) to the last candle? can you please help me?